# QGIS Conversion to_date doesn't work

Tags: qgis, convert, date

I have a table with one of the fields named Date_Time. The features are like 21-5-2016 14:47:00 (field type is string).
I want to extract the dates and add them to a new field with the Conversion function "to_date" in the Field Calculator.

I tried but the conversion has no result. The new field stays empty.
Whether I giving the new field the type "string", "date", etc. and changing the Date_Time field type into date as well (with refractor).
Nothing works. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: perhaps you can try this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17191/does-qgis-support-parsing-of-date-strings-in-tables

Comment: What's the statement you tried?

Comment: I guess `to_date` expects YMD date formatting.

Comment: Since your field contains time components, you would need to parse them with something like `format_date(to_datetime('21-5-2016 14:47:00','d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy/MM/dd')` as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382359/10229

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@AndreJ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9159/andrej) mentioned in his comment, the `to_date` function works with *YYYY-MM-DD* format. But here's a couple of options:

---

1. Only extract the date and add it to a new **string** field using:

   ```
   left("date_time", strpos("date_time", ' '))
   ```

   The above expression extracts all characters to the left of the first 'space' it encounters.

---

2. Create a **python function** in your **Field Calculator** to convert your values to the *YYYY-MM-DD format* which can be stored in a **date** field. You can do this by going to the Field Calculator, click the `Function Editor` tab and enter the following code:

   ```
   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *
   import datetime

   @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
   def convert(field, feature, parent):
       return datetime.datetime.strptime(field, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
   ```

   [image: Function editor]

   When you insert the code, click the *Load* button then go back to the `Expressions` tab and set the relevant options to create a new field. Then use an expression which calls the function and insert the name of your field (e.g. "date_time"):

   ```
   convert("date_time")
   ```

   [image: Expressions]

   Then click *OK* and hopefully your new field will contain the dates:

   [image: Results]